# MSAccess: Get ItemIDs from Recordsetclone into New Table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an AccessDB app where I need to grab the ItemIDs for the current user-applied filter into a new table to use downstream.  Using the subform datasheet .recordsetclone property I can see the desired recordset, .recordcount reports the correct number of records.  Otherwise, the following does not produce the desired temp table and AccessVBA does not complain.

```
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rstItemIDs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strSQL as String
 Set db = CurrentDb

 set rstItemIDs = Forms!Mainform![Data subform].Form.RecordsetClone
 msgbox rstItemIDs.recordcount  'reports the correct result 

 strSQL = "SELECT rstItemIDs.ItemID INTO tempTable FROM rstItemIDs;"
 db.Execute strSQL
```

Is it possible to construct a SQL Select query against a dao.recordset?

Thanks for any pointers you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL will not accept either a `DAO` or `ADODB` `Recordset` as the data source for a query.

However, I'm puzzled that Access does not complain when you try.  With every attempt I made to reproduce your sample code, I got error #3078, *"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'rstItemIDs'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."*

Even `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` did not suppress that error message.

If you're interested in alternatives, you could persist `tempTable` (instead of creating a new version each time), then delete its contents and move through `rstItemIDs` adding each value to the second recordset.  Although that is a RBAR (row by agonizing row) method, it may not be too painful with a small recordset.

A set-based approach could be to create a query based on your form's `.RecordSource` and `.Filter` properties.  For example, with my form's `.RecordSource` as `SELECT * FROM foo` and the current form `.Filter` as `id>10`, this would give me a `SELECT` which returns the form's filtered records:

```vb
Replace(Me.RecordSource, ";", "") & vbcrlf & "AND " & Me.Filter
```

Comment: HansUp - Very helpful!  Your comment prompted me to attempt to use the subform's .Filter property as the basis for my makeTable query.  I have already used RBAR methods elsewhere that have failed miserably to scale.  This approach seems to work just as expected, even with larger datasets.